# How to know how long it take for my background job to run from start to finish?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is there any way I can view my background job start and finish time on Parse Data Browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, parse dashboard does not provide this kind of information. However, you can use the job itself to keep the start and finish time of the job. What I mean, you can use the moment js library to get the start time and finish time when the job ends you can save these information to parse database (to  JobLog table). Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Your welcome. Also do not forget the job has time limit as well. (15 minutes). If your operation exceeds this time limit, then your job is truncated.